# table of signs with tikz

Tags: tkz-tab

I try to make a table of signs in a document via latex and tikz and I get this: (my problem is visible in the table).
How to remedy this?

Script latex :

```
% \documentclass[14pt]{article} 
 %
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{arabart}
% \usepackage{polyglossia}
% \setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
% \setotherlanguage{french} 
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Amiri} 

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[arabic,french]{babel} 

 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage[top=0.9cm, bottom=1cm, left=1.2cm, right=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.5} 
 \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit{$x$ / 1 , $~~~ -3x-\dfrac{1}{3} < 0 ~~ $ / 1}{$-\infty$, $\dfrac{1}{9}$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, - , z,  +, }
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image: table of signs]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard i edited the post

Comment: I've just seen that. Unfortunately, I don't understand exactly what expression you want to make a table of signs of. Could you explain?

Comment: @Bernard I try to make o table of signs of the expression $-3x - \dfrac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was just that the default width of the first column (2cm) is too small. You change it with the optional argument `[lgt=...]`(give a number: lengths are supposed  to be in cm). It's documented on page 10 of the doc.

Also, I suggest you use `medium-sized` fractions, from `nccmath` (about 80% of `\displaystyle`). They'll look nicer in this context than a full \displaystyle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 3.1]{$x$ / 1 , $-3x-\mfrac{1}{3} < 0 $ / 1}{$-\infty$, $\mfrac{1}{9}$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, - , z, +, }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i have an "undefined control sequence" when i use \mfrac instead of \dfrac. did i miss to insert a package or something ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it: you need `nccmath`. It can display all sorts of medium-sized formulæ (integrals, sum symbols, &c.). A useful complement to amsmath (or better, to mathtools).

Comment: @Bernard Veryyyyy good +1.